# SubReport size issue

Tags: jasper-reports, width, subreport

I have the following issue related to subreports using iReport:
I have the main report (Page Width: 595 - Column Width: 535) and a subreport (Page Width: 535 - Column Width: 535). The problem arises when I was told to add more margin in the main report which would led to less space than 535, because when the subreport is rendered, I can't manage to keep it inside the boundaries of the content (and If I try to compact the subreport content I can't coz I have erase every blank space).
How could I solve this ?. It would be awesome to have a feature that let you treat the subreport as an image, so as to make a "real resize" beyond the page with inside it.
Did I make myself clear ?. I'll be around...

Comment: the ireport version is 3.0.0 !.

Comment: @AgusDesign what happen to this question still open?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, is it a question or a feature request?..., but I will answer:

**No** there is no tag for rendering subreport's as image (that it re-size your text automatically).

You need to **manually re-size** your text ecc in the subreport (with modern IDE this should not be very difficult).

However there are other components as the html component that can achieve your desired behaviour.